# How to remove Bathroom Ceiling Fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I live in an apartment and my bathroom ceiling fan is making really loud noise and I'm trying to replace it. However, I am having a hard time locating the screws to remove the entire box. I've checked all the holes ( see pix ) around the box but it doesn't feel like there's any screws inside for me to remove.

Does anyone know how to take this thing down ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is this between floors or in an attic space?

Comment: this is between floors.  I'm on the 3rd floor in a 4 floor apartment.

Comment: These are mounted to ceiling framing prior to ceiling finishing. Getting it out without damaging ceiling is not easy and may require cutting the box with an angle grinder.  If you own the apartment that maybe something you wish to do.

Answer (score 6):

Most of those fans have brackets attached to the sides of the housing that extend and are nailed into the studs. Since it's the motor making the noise, try unplugging it from the housing and removing those silver screws. You should be able to remove the motor and fan impeller. Now try to clean it up and dab a few drops of oil on the motor bearings.Re install it and see if it's better.

Once the motor's removed, you'll probably see the mounting bracket sleeves or nails going into to studs that hold the housing in. You could then try to work those lose. Since this is an apartment, check with the landlord before doing any work. He might even have a replacement motor that you can just screw back in.

Comment: https://www.carnes.com/ventilation.phtml.   Maybe this link will get to the company that makes these perhaps a new motor assembly is easiest and least expensive option

Comment: I like JACK's answer.  I was in Colorado for a few months, staying in a triplex, dealing with family issues and the bathroom fan was clearly failing.   It's not easy tearing out the fan housing and replacing it with an entirely new unit. Often the wrong size or damage done, resulting in sheetrock repair.   I found a company in Boulder that rebuilt electric motors.  I thought maybe I could get get a replacement motor, so I took the old one in and said they could just clean it up, replace the bearings, lube it and it'd be good to go. $30 later (cash! only), had a perfectly functioning motor.

Comment: @JACK Thanks!  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I had one (not very similar to yours) and took the motor in to ask for a replacement. They said they did not have the motor, but they could sell me the whole unit, including the box. I just had to put the new motor in the old box and throw away the new box!